# Android Listview Items not redrawn when they scroll off the screen in Froyo

Tags: android, listview, android-2.2-froyo

I have a listview that when scrolled and the items go off of the screen they are not redrawn when I scroll back to them (the text and checkbox).  In fact, items that are off the bottom of the screen in the listview never get drawn when scrolling to them.  This only happens in Froyo.  Any other version it works just fine.  I have checked and the data is there as expected in the adapter when the getItem method is called, it is just not visible.  The listview item is there (it's occupying the same amount of screen space per item), I just cannot see the text or checkbox once scrolled off screen and back on again.

My code is such:

```
for(checklist cl : checkLists) {
    ArrayList<checklistItem> ChecklistItems = database.getChecklistItems(
                                                  cl.getId());

    ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);                  
    lv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    la = new checklistItemAdapter(this, layoutItem, ChecklistItems);      
    la.setActivity(this);
    lv.setAdapter(la);                

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(cl.getItemText());
    tv.setGravity(1);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 50));
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    tv.setTextSize(28);
    tv.setTextScaleX(2);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);

    layoutChecklist = new LinearLayout(this);                
    layoutChecklist.setOrientation(1);
    layoutChecklist.addView(tv);
    layoutChecklist.addView(lv);

    layoutChecklists.addView(layoutChecklist);
}
```

Comment: What is checkListItemAdapter?

Comment: @Android Addict: Why are you calling `setScrollingCacheEnabled()`? Where does `layoutItem` come from? And what is `layoutChecklists`?

Comment: checkListItemAdapter is an Adapter extender specific to my list design.

Comment: My thoughts on the setScrollingCacheEnabled() would resolve the very issue that I am facing.

Comment: layoutItem is a defined layout that I reference in another part of the class and pass to the procedure with the snippet you see here.  As with the layoutItem, layoutChecklists is a defined layout referenced in code.

Comment: As stated in my original post, the issue only exists in Froyo.  All other versions of the OS do not have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using a ViewGroup (preferred method per documentation) instead of creating all of the views in code.